# sending an email from a php page

Tags: php

Im trying to get an email to send from my php page to an email address that is set.

The email is being sent and received at the expected email address. But the contents within the email are not as expected. I got the code from watching a tutorial on youtube.

However when looking at the email is displays exactly as the code below, doesn't give me the values behind the variables e.g $name shows up in the email as $name

Any ideas?

The code im using is;

```
<?php 

require_once 'header.php';

$to = 'emailaddress ';
$subject = 'CSG';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['emailaddress'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$body = <<<EMAIL 

Hi $name, You have recently requested a notification of your password on the Coleg Sir Gar Loan Syste site. 

From $name 

EMAIL;

$header = '$email';

if ($_POST){        
    mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);
    $feedback = 'Email Sent';
}

?>
```

Comment: Try to use `{$name}` in the heredoc string

Comment: what's this supposed to do? `$header = '$email';` - RTM http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- display the email address as the sender in my mailbox

Comment: your header is failing you; again... read the manual.

Comment: you've my answer below @Mucca019

Comment: @Mucca019 I've made a few edits since my originally posted answer. You will need to reload it in order to see the changes/additions. Please read it in its entirety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, variables do not get parsed inside single quotes, that's why you're seeing `$email` rather than the email itself inside the email body.

So change `$header = '$email';` to either `$header = "$email";` or remove the quotes entirely.

I.e.: `$header = $email;`

Then the header is failing you. It expects to be a `From:` (email address) - The "From" in your mail will come back as your server's name rather than the (intended) email address from the person sending it.

Consult the manual:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Sidenote about your heredoc.

Even though mail is going out, you still have a trailing space in your opening identifier:

`$body = <<<EMAIL`

and that may throw a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<<' (T_SL)` error.

- Error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

---

Testing this came back as:

```
email@example.com

Hi Fred, You have recently requested a notification of your password on the Coleg Sir Gar Loan Syste site.

From Fred
```

and the "From:" as `default@cpanel.example.com` rather than `whoever@example_mailer.xxx`.

As noted in comments by [dieend](https://stackoverflow.com/users/696686/dieend), you can try bracing the variables `{$var}`, however with or without them, produced the same results for me.

If that still doesn't work, then it may be caused by the trailing space in your opening identifier; **you need to remove it.**

Copy/paste exactly as shown:

```
$body = <<< EMAIL

Hi {$name}, You have recently requested a notification of your password on the Coleg Sir Gar Loan Syste site. 

From {$name} - {$email}

EMAIL;

$header = "From:" . $email; // Now you have a valid From

if ($_POST){
    mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);
    echo $feedback = 'Email Sent';
}
```

---

**Final notes:**

- If that still doesn't solve the question, then I for one am unable to reproduce.

Comment: Thanks Fred, All working as I'd hoped now. Few typos in my html form created few issues after I followed your help but managed to find them and resolved

Comment: @Mucca019 You are most welcome. I was glad to have helped, *cheers* :-)